# Are there any differences between the movie adaptation and the novel of The Sky Crawlers?

Tags: the-sky-crawlers

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sky_Crawlers_(film)) mentions that the *The Sky Crawlers* movie is an adaptation of the novel. While the article tells the story in detail (if not overly detail for Wikipedia), the [article on the novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sky_Crawlers) doesn't have any summary for each novel.

Does the movie faithfully adapt the novel? Are there any differences between the movie adaptation and the novel?